# VSTS Build Management not restoring 3rd party DLL references

Tags: azure-pipelines

Good afternoon,

I'm new to VSTS Build Management. I'm attempting to take our current solution (which builds fine on our dev machines) and get a successful build within VSTS Build Manager. I'm failing horribly so far and would like just a direction i should be looking as i bet this is some simple configuration that is missing either within VSTS or within my solution.

I have the following structure in source control

1. **$/Core/Core/Solution** <- .sln lives here
2. **$/Core/Core/Solution/assemblies** <- 3rd party DLL here
3. **$/Core/Core/Solution/Project/** <- .csproj lives here

My projects reference the DLL in the assemblies folder whihc is checked into source control and sits at the root with the .sln file

In my .csproj file i can verify that it contains the following entry (I'm going to focus on one of the DLL's i'm trying to reference, however multiple DLLs in the assemblies folder are giving me trouble)

```
<Reference Include="ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud">
   <HintPath>..\assemblies\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

When taking a look at the "Get Sources" Logs i see the following for the assemblies folder:

```
> 2018-03-18T00:27:00.1610080Z D:\a\3\s\assemblies:
> 2018-03-18T00:27:00.1610395Z Getting README.md
```

There are about a dozen other DLL's in that folder that it **does not** seem to be pulling down for source control (unless i am missing something)

I have even attempted to provide MSBuild Arguments for the Build Solution phase of the VSTS Build:

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package
>   /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
>   /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\"
>   /p:ReferencePath="..\assemblies"

Still i get the following error:

> 018-03-18T00:28:28.2671124Z ##[error]Project\Global\Wurfl.cs(5,7):
>   Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ScientiaMobile' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> When looking at the Build Solution logs i do see many attempts to
>   locate the reference:
>
> 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7512305Z           For SearchPath "..\assemblies".
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7512558Z           Considered
>   "..\assemblies\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd", but it didn't exist.
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7512735Z           Considered
>   "..\assemblies\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll", but it didn't exist.
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7512882Z           Considered
>   "..\assemblies\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe", but it didn't exist.
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7513015Z           For SearchPath
>   "{HintPathFromItem}". 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7513176Z
>   Considered "..\assemblies\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll", but it
>   didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7513310Z           For SearchPath
>   "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}". 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7513474Z
>   Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.2\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7513695Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.2\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7514373Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.2\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7514564Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7514733Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7515106Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7515281Z           For
>   SearchPath "{AssemblyFoldersFromConfig:C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\AssemblyFolders.config,v4.6.2}".
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7515458Z           Considered "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7515656Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7515824Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7516021Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SqlDb\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7516201Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SqlDb\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7516385Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SqlDb\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7516593Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7516766Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7516958Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7517133Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.5\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7517505Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.5\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7517737Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.5\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7517914Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v4.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7518118Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v4.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7518298Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v4.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7518536Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7518711Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7518877Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7519067Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.5\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7519238Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.5\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7519438Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.5\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7519615Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7519809Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7520771Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7520990Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7521223Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7521428Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7521650Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7521847Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7522044Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7522275Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v2.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7522567Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v2.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7522803Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v2.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7523005Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7523227Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7523603Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7523956Z           For
>   SearchPath
>   "{Registry:Software\Microsoft.NETFramework,v4.6.2,AssemblyFoldersEx}".
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7524102Z           Considered AssemblyFoldersEx
>   locations. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7524207Z           For SearchPath
>   "{AssemblyFolders}". 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7524340Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7524519Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7524675Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7524837Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\SDK\Assemblies\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd", but it
>   didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7525200Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\SDK\Assemblies\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll", but it
>   didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7525357Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\SDK\Assemblies\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe", but it
>   didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7525532Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy
>   V3\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd", but it didn't exist.
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7525682Z           Considered "C:\Program
>   Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll", but
>   it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7525829Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy
>   V3\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe", but it didn't exist.
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7526012Z           Considered "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7526180Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7526341Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe",
>   but it didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7526516Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset
>   v3.11\SDK\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd", but it didn't exist.
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7526664Z           Considered "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\SDK\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll", but it
>   didn't exist. 2018-03-18T00:28:22.7526836Z           Considered
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset
>   v3.11\SDK\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe", but it didn't exist.
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7526964Z           For SearchPath "{GAC}".
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7527080Z           Considered
>   "ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud", which was not found in the GAC.
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7527457Z           For SearchPath "{RawFileName}".
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7527577Z           Considered treating
>   "ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud" as a file name, but it didn't exist.
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7527691Z           For SearchPath "bin\Release\".
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7527807Z           Considered
>   "bin\Release\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.winmd", but it didn't exist.
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7527957Z           Considered
>   "bin\Release\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll", but it didn't exist.
>   2018-03-18T00:28:22.7528082Z           Considered
>   "bin\Release\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.exe", but it didn't exist.

So obviously the build fails.

My questions are what am i missing to get a reference pulled in correctly when dealing with 3rd party DLL in a folder outside of the project but checked in to source control. Specifically i need to know what i need to do to get this going in VSTS Build as this setup works just fine in Visual Studio. A more broad question i have is what is the best practice to using and referencing 3rd party DLLs that facilitiate the VSTS Build process finding what it needs?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Is your NuGet.config set up to pull from your Package Management feed?

Comment: So the NuGet.config at the root of my solution has one line: <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />, however my solution is setup to reference this feed and does restore from this VSTS Packages feed. In the Nuget Restore step logs i do see references to CredentialProvider and do see it attempting to do something with the VSTS Packages feed. No references after that point in terms of actually getting the package.

Comment: When you say "your solution" is set up to reference the feed, do you mean you added the feed within Visual Studio? Because that's not the same as configuring your project -- `nuget.config` controls that.

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, that is what i meant. Clearly i have not configured this to function outside of a VS build. I guess a few questions come up from your question to me. 1) Should my nuget.config for the solution have all nugets used by the solution or just my VSTS Packages feed packages? 2) If it currently holds no references as you described, how then is it successful in getting all the other NuGet package not found in the VSTS Packages feed 3) Should the nuget.config file be pushed to source control even if the VSTS build definition is referencing the .sln file?

Comment: Think i got the answer to at least one of those questions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/_shared/nuget-step-qa

Comment: Added package sources to my nuget.config with no change to the build...

Comment: @Nugs What's the result if you specify VSTS feed directly in NuGet task?

Comment: What are you using for source control Git or TFVC?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the VSTS feed in NuGet task:

[image]

Otherwise, you need to select Feeds in my NuGet.config option.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to solve this.

**1 - Change and test your build**

Change your build definition to clean sources. So that you start fresh.
Run your build. It will fail, I know.
Take a look at the get sources step and search in the log if all your files are being downloaded.

**2 - Your assemblies folder**

$/Core/Core/Solution/assemblies <- 3rd party DLL here
Apparently use are using TFVC. So, check that the assemblies folder has permission set for (allowing) for Project Build Service and for Project Collection Build Service. The minimum permission is to read. But I would give them full permission if not set, or denied.

When these users have no permission, the build system simply does not download your DLLs.

**3 - Check how you configured your workspace on build definition**

Assuming you are using TFVC, at your build definition, take a look at the "Get sources" step.
Your workspace settings must map the same structure as they are in stored in the repo.

[image]

It not necessarily has to be mapped as I should in the image, but you have to make sure that you end up with a local source structure that respects your server structure, like:

- /
- /assemblies
- /project

You will need this so that your instruction in .csproj can find your dll:

**..\assemblies**

```
<Reference Include="ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud">
   <HintPath>..\assemblies\ScientiaMobile.WurflCloud.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```